# From a descending ordered set of times and values, how can I find the last time the highest value appears, using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of minutely temperature data that covers many days, and I want to get the maximum temperature reached on a specific day. I can do this using the following SQL query (note that it follows Met Office guidelines, which derive the maximum using data from 09:00 to 21:00 and not from 00:00 to 23:59) also, today's date is added for illustration purposes:

```
      SELECT timestamp, shieldedTemp FROM stationData 
      WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2017-01-29 09:00:00' AND '2017-01-29 21:00:00' 
      ORDER BY shieldedTemp DESC LIMIT 1
```

This simply orders all the records between the two times and returns the top one. However, I have realised by looking at a graph that sometimes the temperature will level out after reaching the maximum, and will remain at that same maximum temperature for some time before beginning to fall. In this case, the maximum will be reported as the FIRST time the maximum value was reached.

What I want to do is return the LAST time the maximum was reached. Can this be done by modifying the above query, or will I have to return all the ordered values for the whole day and then iterate over them to find the greatest index with the same temperature as the first index?

Comment: what happens if this maximum covers more than one day?

Comment: @McNets It wouldn't, as the current query gets the maximum from between two times in the same day

Comment: I believe you have two answers below. Why did you just not add a sort order on `timestamp` as you did on `shieldedTemp ` in your original query ?

Comment: @JasonKrs Don't know why but that didn't actually occur to me! Thanks

Comment: Pay close attention to the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add timestamp to the order sentence.

```
SELECT timestamp, shieldedTemp 
FROM stationData 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2017-01-29 09:00:00' AND '2017-01-29 21:00:00' 
ORDER BY shieldedTemp DESC, timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/VJR22230

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select timestamp, shieldedTemp
from stationData
where 
    timestamp between '2017-01-29 09:00:00' and '2017-01-29 21:00:00'
    and shieldedTemp = (
        select max(shieldedTemp)
        from stationData
        where timestamp between '2017-01-29 09:00:00' and '2017-01-29 21:00:00'
    )
order by timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

**Explanation**

The subquery extracts maximum temperature for the timestamp range you are looking for. The outer query gets all records between the same timestamp range but only for the max temp.

Order the resultset based on highest timestamp first and extract just the first record.